# HTTP ERROR 404 after page refresh in ANgular JS1

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using http-server package to run my angular js project. My directory structure is below:-

angulardemo/app/public/controller

angulardemo/app/public/app.js

angulardemo/app/public/index.html

angulardemo/app/public/view

ang my app.js file is

```js
var app = angular.module('angulardemo', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
  .constant('API_URL', 'http://127.0.0.1:8001')
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
   
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};

   /**
    * 
    * Checks for url access
    */
   resolver = function (access){

    return {
     load: function($q, AuthService, $location){
      if(access){

       return true
      }else{

       if(AuthService.checkLogin()){

        return true;
       }
       else{

        $location.path("/login");
       }
      }
     }
    }
    
   }

   $routeProvider
   .when('/', {

    templateUrl : "/view/home.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
   .when('/home', {

    templateUrl : "/view/home.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
   .when('/about', {

    templateUrl : "/view/about.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
   .when('/team', {

    templateUrl : "/view/team.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
   .when('/work', {

    templateUrl : "/view/work.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
   .when('/price', {

    templateUrl : "/view/price.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
   .when('/users/:user_type', {

    templateUrl : "/view/developers.html",
    controller : 'UsersController'
   })
   .when('/user/show/:id', {

    templateUrl : "/view/user.details.html",
    controller : 'UsersController'
   })
   .when('/contact', {

    templateUrl : "/view/contact.html",
    controller : 'PagesController'
   })
         .when('/register', {

             controller: 'AuthController',
             templateUrl: '/view/auth/register.html',
    resolve:{

     loggedIn: function(AuthService, $location){
      
      if(!AuthService.checkLogin())
       return true;
      else
       $location.path("/home");
     }
    }

         })
         .when('/login', {

             controller: 'AuthController',
             templateUrl: '/view/auth/login.html',
    resolve:{

     loggedIn: function(AuthService, $location){
      
      if(!AuthService.checkLogin())
       return true;
      else
       $location.path("/home");
     }
    }

         })
   .when('/dashboard', {

             controller: 'DashboardController',
             templateUrl: '/view/dashboard/index.html',
    pageTitle: 'dashboard',
    resolve:resolver(false)
   })
   .when('/users_personal/:id', {

             controller: 'UsersController',
             templateUrl: '/view/users/personal.html',
    pageTitle: 'personal_details',
    resolve:resolver(false)
   })
   .when('/users_edu/:id', {

             controller: 'UsersController',
             templateUrl: '/view/users/edu.html',
    pageTitle: 'edu_details',
    resolve:resolver(false)
   })
   .when('/users_contact/:id', {

             controller: 'UsersController',
             templateUrl: '/view/users/contact.html',
    pageTitle: 'contact_details',
    resolve:resolver(false)
   })
   .when('/users_other/:id', {

             controller: 'UsersController',
             templateUrl: '/view/users/other.html',
    pageTitle: 'other',
    resolve:resolver(false)
   })
         .when('/logout', {
    
    resolve : {
              logout: function ($routeParams, $location, $http, API_URL){
      $http.get(API_URL + "/api/auth/logout").success(function (response) {

       if(response === "OK"){
        
        localStorage.removeItem('auth');
        $location.path('/login').replace();
       }
      })
               }
             }
         })
   .otherwise({
             redirectTo: '/',
      }); 
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
   }).hashPrefix('*');
  }).run(['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies) {

   $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
  }]);
```

when I am running project using "http-server" **with in the app directory** command I got url as  http://127.0.0.1:8080
 http://192.168.10.137:8080

all the pages are working fine but when I am refreshing the page I am getting This 127.0.0.1 page can’t be found

No web page was found for the web address: http://127.0.0.1:8080/team
HTTP ERROR 404

So can anyone please tell that what wrong thing is here. and provide the solution.

See the directory structure in git hub:-

https://github.com/sanjaysamant/angulardemo/tree/local/app

**Angular js files are in the public directory**

Thanks

Please see terminal screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are on a sub-URL such as `/team` and you refresh the page, the Node-Server looks for a HTML-File that is in the folder `team` on your server, which is not what you want. You need the server to redirect all those URL's to your index.html so that it loads the Angular Application, which can then properly initialize the correct page.

You can try the following in your server.js file:

```
//routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./controllers/auth/auth.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/users/users.controller'));
app.use('/api/user/', require('./controllers/users/users.controller'));
// Redirect unmatched routes (All specific routes such as /api/* need to be before this call)
app.use(redirectUnmatched);

function redirectUnmatched(req, res) {
  res.redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response But I am getting same error. and you are talking about server to redirect  all those URL's to your index.html . So can you tell me please which server I need to use. I am new in angular and node. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the server needs to redirect all the URLs, as you always want to load one index.html File. Node is in this case running as the server, whereas everything of angular and all html-Files are the Frontend (client). Can you show me what your server.js file looks like and if you have any error or info messages when running http-server. If you haven't done it yet you also need to stop and restart the server after you made the changes.

Comment: https://github.com/sanjaysamant/angulardemo/tree/local/app and one more thing when I am running only angularjs then why should I need the server.js file? and I have updated the screenshot image above. Thanks

Comment: This looks like what you posted in your question. Did you commit and push the changes?

Comment: Sorry for that. You can check now the updated code, and one more thing is the .htaccess file will be effective here?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What @Chnoch suggested is correct, however I want to give you a different approach.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res)
{
    res.send('/path/to/index.html');
});
```

Because all requests for a page will be a GET requests, you don't need to specify POST, and with this approach it will preserve the current URL you are on (eg. if you were on http://127.0.0.1:8080/team you will refresh and still be on /team), wheras @Chnoch's approach will always redirect you back to http://127.0.0.1:8080/.

What this will do is for any request that can't be resolved by the Node server, it will just render plain index page that can then be handled by Angular's ngRoute to display templates (you can also use templating engines like EJS or Pug with this, just replace the res.send with the rendering function).

Just make sure that the above code is after ALL other routes you want to be resolved by the Node server (eg. your API etc.) so it doesn't interfere with routes after it, since this is a catch all route.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am getting same error again.

Comment: and did not get the "LL other routes you want to be resolved by the Node server ". I am using http-server package for running angular js code. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, unsure of why the error is happening so I can't help further unfortunately. And what I meant by that is the code I provided is a catch all, so any routes that are defined after it will never be reached, so I was just advising you to make sure it goes last